# relationship between trace and integral

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, measure-theory

While reading a paper, I found the following equation, which isn't clear.

> **Lemma** : Suppose $\Sigma$ is a positive definite $p \times p$ matrix, $s_1\ge\dots \ge s_p > 0$ are eigenvalues of the $\Sigma$, and $H(s) := p^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^p\mathbb I(s \ge s_i)$. Then,
> $$\frac{1}{p}\text{Tr}\Bigl(a\Sigma^2(I + b\Sigma)^{-2}\Bigr)
> = \int\frac{as^2}{(1 + bs)^2}dH(s),$$
> where $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Intuitively, I can guess that $a\Sigma^2$ is related to $as^2$ in the numerator, while $(I + b\Sigma)^2$ to $(1+bs)^2$ in the denonimator. But, I want to clearly understand how the **'trace'** is associated with the integral $\int dH(s)$ and the matrices with the integrand.

Further, I've covered measure theory (by Stein) until recently. If the above equation covers some mathematic concepts over the measure theory, such as functional analysis I'd like to know which concepts I have to see to clearly understand the above equation.

Any help or recommendations would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side of your equality is
$$\tag1
\frac1p\sum_{j=1}^p\frac{a s_j^2}{(1+bs_j)^2}.
$$
And the right hand side is nothing but $(1)$ written as an integral with respect to the measure $\mu$ where $\mu(\{s_j\})=\frac1p$ for all $j$ and $\mu(\mathbb R)=1$. A more intuitive  way to write the measure would be
$$
\mu=\frac1p\sum_{j=1}^p\delta_{s_j},
$$
where $\delta_s$ denotes the Dirac measure centered at $s$.